# How to be able to use "." AND "," in INPUT element of type with lang="fr"?

Tags: html, input, localization, numbers

I'm using this kind of input in my FORM :

```
<input type="number" name="largeur[0]" step="1" min="0.1" lang="fr"/>
```

But, if in that one, I type the value "100.1", it won't send anything when the form will be submitted. only "100,1" will be send because it's the correct syntax of a decimal in local "fr-fr". Is there a way to allow both "." and ",", please ?

Thanks for your help.